# Create an amortization table with SQL

Tags: sql, programming

I have a list of credits, let's assume they are only two for ease:

Credit #1 and credit #2: One has 3 months of payments missing and the other has 6 months left of payments.

It would like to obtain a table which can produce a dataset with the due date of the following payments:

Original dataset:

[image: Original dataset]

Desired dataset:

[image: Desired dataset]